# Extracting/copying multiple non adjacent cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to extract cells which have a specific colour from an Excel file. I can locate all of them with find/replace and have them selected, but if I try to copy them I get the error message "This action won't work on multiple selections", because not all those cells are adjacent.
Is there a way to be able to copy/paste cells which are not adjacent?

I only tried with find/replace > Options / Format /Choose format from Cell.
So, I have selected all the cells I need, but still no way to be able to copy them.
I haven't used VBA as I don't know that language